# Read out the state of the state machine

Tags: stateflow

experts ;) 
Working on the following problem. 
Have a state machine with the states A and B. 
State block 1 is called: A, info in the block:  `entry: A=1;`
State block 2 is called: B, info in the block: `entry: A=0;`
Conditions for switching from A to B: `Input(494)>494 & Input(631)<631`
Condition for switching from B to A: `Input(494)<494 & Input(631)>631`
Input is a vector with 1000 values. 
The running time of the Simulink simulation is 1000 seconds. Scope only shows me 1 every time, but it should be 0 between 494 and 631.

Is anything wrong with the conditions??

Comment: The values of the input vector: 1,2,3, ...., 1000.

Comment: ok I thing the conditions are wrong, but how can I write that the output of the state flow schould be zero between the values 494 and 631 and 1 otherweise??

Comment: Ok I tried a following: `[Input(494:631)]`. But I see the following error massage: `Illegal use of a matrix or vector type where a scalar was expected`.